# NASM not working with /dev/stdout as output

Tags: shell, nasm

My task is to create program generating some assembly code based on input on stdin, and output machine code on stdout.

My approach looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f ./lc ]; then
    gcc lc.c -o lc
fi

./lc | nasm /dev/stdin -fbin -o /dev/stdout
```

LC reads from stdin and outputs assembly code to stdout. Then i pipe assembly code to nasm that is reading from it's stdin. Finally I want to output machine code to /dev/stdout.

But, i get such error:

```
nasm:fatal: unable to open output file `/dev/stdout'
```

To verify /dev/stdout works, i checked it like that:

```
$ cat < /dev/stdin > /dev/stdout
test
test
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried sudoing, no effect. Is there some commandline switch for this application to output code to stdout? My best bet is avoid creating **any** temporary source files and work purely on streams.

Comment: Do you have a `/dev/stdout` on your system? Bash has a special case for redirections to/from this name, so your test is inconclusive. Use `dd if=/dev/stdin of=/dev/stdout` instead, or just `ls -l /dev/stdout`

Comment: Going to check it out later, but if CAT worked, i thought its okay

Comment: This is not the case, because `cat` never sees or opens these filenames. Since they are redirections, they are handled by bash. Here's `man bash` under Redirection: "*Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in redirections, as described in the following table:

/dev/fd/fd
If fd is a valid integer, file descriptor fd is duplicated.

/dev/stdin
File descriptor 0 is duplicated.

/dev/stdout
File descriptor 1 is duplicated.
[..]*"

Comment: @thatotherguy Checked out DD, doesn't work.